# How to access keys and values in Koala json response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala

I'm using Koala gem in a Rails 3.2 app to return a list of user's friends.

I think the response is a JSON hash in the format:

[{"name"=>"FB Friend 1 1", "id"=>"123456780"}, {"name"=>"FB Friend 2", "id"=>"987654321"}]

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to manipulate this format for use elsewhere.

Basically I'm trying to add a select field where the options are the friends, something like

```
<select name="friends[friend_id]">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="123456789">FB Friend 1</option>
  <option value="987654321">FB Friend 2</option>
</select>
```

As the response is not an array, I can't just use :id and :name for the select. How to I access the keys and values?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= select_tag 'friends[friends_id]', options_for_select([['none', nil]] + list) %>
```